# Tracking user activities

Tags: c#, asp.net, tracking

I need to create classes that take care of user activities.for eg.know his location.what he commented on.how long has he been on the page.of he read a particular article etc.
Can someone please help me with this .
Thank You

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Looking for answers dear ...not lectures!

Comment: You can logging user requests and counting specific actions(for example - add comment request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) will give out some of this information for you without you having to implement anything.

Implementing something like this will be very time consuming and quite challenging. So it might be a really fun and interesting task! But in most cases using an existing system will be what you want :-)

Comment: And there is a library that might help you out, https://github.com/AttackPattern/CSharpAnalytics